# What is the difference between tessconfigs and configs in Tesseract-OCR?

Tags: tesseract

In Tesseract-OCR, there are 2 folders in tessdata - `tessdata/configs` and `tessdata/tessconfigs`:

[image]

Both seem to contain config files - for example `makebox` is in configs while `batch.nochop` is in tessconfig.

So what is the difference between them? Why split the config files between 2 folders? Do they contain different categories of config files?